# want to install python -m pip install pyautogui===0.9.39 but am facing this

Tags: python, pip

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Python27\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\ranafa~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-7_8uzi\\pyscreeze\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\ranafa~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-7_8uzi\\pyscreeze\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'c:\users\ranafa~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-7_8uzi\pyscreeze\pip-egg-info'
     cwd: c:\users\ranafa~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-7_8uzi\pyscreeze\
Complete output (3 lines):
C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'requires_python'
  warnings.warn(msg)
error in PyScreeze setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Is the triple `===` intended?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%27install_requires%27+must+be+a+string+or+list+of+strings+containing+valid+project%2Fversion+requirement+specifiers